# Getting different answers when using Shell and Disk Method on the same problem?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, volume

I need a quick proof here.  I've done this problem in both Shell and Disk Method, and get a different answer for each respectively. The book says the right answer is 8π and uses Disk Method, I agree, but when I use Shell Method, I get 18π.  Can someone tell me my mistake please?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the shell method, it should be
$$2\pi\int_{0}^3(y)(3-y)\,dy$$
If you draw a horizontal strip at level $y$, you get$\;r(y)=y,\;h(y)=3-y$.

Comment: But I am rotating around the line y axis, why is there a (3-y)?

Comment: The problem says rotate about the $x$-axis. The horizontal strips at level y have left endpoint $(y,y)$ and right endpoint $(3,y)$, so the strip has length $h(y)=3-y$. To set up these problems, you should always draw a representative strip.

Comment: Note: The strips must be _in_ the region. So the horizontal strips are not strips of thickness $\Delta y$ between the line $y=x$ and the $y$-axis. Rather, they're horizontal strips of thickness $\Delta y$ between the line $y=x$ and the line $x=3$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^3 \pi x^2\mathsf dx = \int_0^3 2 \pi y(3-y)\mathsf d y = 9\pi$$

The first method cuts the cone into discs of radius $x$ perpendicular to the x-axis; for $x\in[0;3]$.   These discs have area of $\pi x^2$.

The second method cuts the cone into shells of radius $y$ and height $(3-y)$ parallel to the x-axis; for $y\in[0;3]$.   The cylindric shells are generated by rotating the line segments $\overline{(y,y)(3,y)}$ in circular orbits around the x-axis.   These have length $3-y$, and trace circles of radius $y$, and thus generate cylindric shells of surface area $2\pi y(3-y)$.

Comment: But I am rotating around the line y axis, why is there a (3-y)?

Comment: @Jesse You are orbiting a horizontal line segement that intersects the *green triangle* -- from point $(y,y)$ to point $(3,y)$ -- around the *x-axis*.  Each shell is thus an open cylinder of height $3-y$ and base cicumference $2\pi y$.